# Using bidirectional weak pointers

Tags: ios, objective-c, weak-references

I'm finding myself in a little conundrum.
I have a situation where I could potentially create a circular dependency between two sibling level objects.  I want both to stay in memory, and neither instance is more/less important than the other.  Should I just arbitrarily make one side's pointer weak, and the other strong, or could I get away with making both sides weak?

Say you had an object model with a structure like this...

```
ADatabaseTable
   -(NSArray)fields
       FieldInfo  (field A)
       FieldInfo  (field B)
   -(NSArray)values
       FieldValue (field A - record 1)
       FieldValue (field A - record 2)
       FieldValue (field B - record 1)
       FieldValue (field B - record 2)
```

...and you want the FieldValue to have a reference to FieldInfo and vice-versa.

How would you specify the property attributes (weak/strong) to have these refer to each other?

Thanks

Comment: What events would make you want to remove a `FieldValue` from the table? What events would make you want to remove a `FieldInfo`?

Comment: Well, I guess  the app shutting down, or the view that's displaying this information going away.

Comment: Is it reasonable to have the parent `table` own both of these siblings to define their lifecycle? Would you ever have a `FieldInfo` or `FieldValue` without a parent table?

Comment: They would always have a parent table.   I'm just considering the convenience of working from a 'FieldValue' back to its `FieldInfo` or vice versa, rather than each having to go through the table and have the table do some kind of enumerating an array to find the corresponding object.

Comment: Should the whole `ADatabaseTable` and all its children be deallocated when the view goes away? Or does the view just display a single field or value?

Comment: It would display one or more records in a grid view, so when the `ADatabaseTable` goes away, everything under it would go too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the `ADatabaseTable` has strong references to the `fields` array and the `values` array.

A normal `NSArray` keeps strong references to its elements, so you already don't have to worry about the elements in the arrays going away.

So you can make the infos and the values refer to each other weakly.